# jQuery FormatCurrency plugin: how do I change the default of an option?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to use the [jquery-formatcurrency](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-formatcurrency/wiki/Usage) plugin.

I need to set the `roundToDecimalPlace` option to 0 by default. That is, I don't want to specify that everytime I invoke `jQueryObject.val().formatCurrency({roundToDecimalPlace: 0});`

Instead, I just want to say `jQueryObject.val().formatCurrency();`

I tried setting it like this:
`$.formatCurrency.defaults.roundToDecimalPlace = 0;` but `defaults` is undefined.

I also tried `$.formatCurrency.defaults = {roundToDecimalPlace: 0};` but that has no effect.

I found that $.formatCurrency only provides an object called `region` to configure, but doing `$.formatCurrency.region.roundToDecimalPlace = 0;` didn't help.

Comment: I suspect you need to change the actual plugin code to achieve this.  I'd find the `roundToDecimalPlace` property in the plugin code and set it to `0` as required.

Comment: :( I really want to avoid that...

Comment: But you can't just invent functionality that a plugin does not have... You can't just use "defaults" if there isn't a `defaults` method.  It has to be there programmatically within the original plugin.  If it bothers you that much, you can create you own method which calls the `jQueryObject.val().formatCurrency({roundToDecimalPlace: 0});` by passing in your `jQueryObject` and returns the value that you want.  This way you can program it once and reuse the code every time you want to format a currency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just invent functionality for a plugin such as `defaults`.  It has to have the functionality programmed into the plugin, ready to be used.

If you're bothered about programming this more than once, create your own method that you can reuse again and again, but you have only defined `roundToDecimalPlace` once.

For example, the code below can have the jQueryObject passed to it and returns the formatted value back:

```
function FormatMyCurrency(jQueryObject)
{
    var formattedCurrency= jQueryObject.val().formatCurrency({roundToDecimalPlace: 0});

    return formattedCurrency;
}
```

It can then be used again and again using:

```
var myFormattedCurrency = FormatMyCurrency(jQueryObject);
```